# Serre's vanishing theorem and global generation.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Given a short exact sequence of coherent sheaves on a projective variety if we tensor the sequence with $\mathcal{O}(n)$ with a high enough $n$, everything becomes globally generated and by Serre's vanishing theorem taking the global sections becomes exact. I wonder whether it is possible to prove this without Serre's vanishing theorem. Serre's theorem applies for the proper varieties, I wonder whether the fact mentioned above remains true for let's say if we remove a high codimension subvariety from a projective variety? Like $\mathbb{P}^2\setminus \text{pt}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $L$ be a line through $p\in\mathbb{P}^2$ and let $X=\mathbb{P}^2-\{p\}$ and $M=L-\{p\}$. You have an exact sequence of coherent sheaves, $0\to O_X(-1)\to O_X\to O_M\to 0$. Easy to see that $H^0(O_X(n))\to H^0(O_M(n))$ is not surjective for any $n$, since $H^0(O_M(n))$ is not finite dimensional over the base field.

Comment: Dear Mohan, allow me to add (for the benefit of beginners) a few explanations to your splendid example. The point is that every line bundle on $X$ extends to $\mathbb P^2$. This is because on a smooth variety line bundles are represented by Weil divisors, which extend through codimension $\geq 2$ closed subvarieties: see Hartshorne Proposition 6.5 (b). From there we can apply Hartogs's theorem (Hartshorne, Chapter I, Exercise 3.20 (a)) and deduce that the canonical restriction map $H^0(O_{\mathbb P^2}(n)) \to H^0(O_X(n))$ is bijective, so that $H^0(O_X(n))$  is indeed finite-dimensional.

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg Thank you for your expansions and clarifications. Will help the beginners .

Comment: Dear Mohan, it is a pleasure for me to be able to comment on an answer of such high quality.